# Why this expression simplfies to 0.+0.I?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
 Simplify[E^(-0.2` (1 - τ2)) (2^-(-21 + τ1)^2 Sin[
          1.256` + π (-21 + τ1)] + 
        2^-(-20 + τ1)^2 Sin[
          1.256` + π (-20 + τ1)]) (2^-(-21 + τ2)^2 Sin[
          1.256` + π (-21 + τ2)] + 
        2^-(-20 + τ2)^2 Sin[1.256` + π (-20 + τ2)]) Sin[
       0.9797958971132712` (1 - τ2)] (1/2 E^(-0.2` (1 - τ1))
          Sin[0.9797958971132712` (1 - τ1)] + 
        E^(-0.2` (-τ1 + τ2))
          Sin[0.9797958971132712` (-τ1 + τ2)])]
```

(mma11 win7 64bit)

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82765)

Comment: Use `Simplify[expr] // Chop`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon It may not be that problem.

Comment: @WateSoyan well, it is your job to state the problem well. So what did you expect, `12`?

Comment: Probably precision-related. For any value of the parameters that I try, I get extremely small values, *effectively* zero. Remember that any number that has a decimal point is considered *inexact*, so the argument that "but it's not *exactly* zero!" doesn't apply. A counterargument is: Have you investigated how much precision would be lost to roundoff during such a calculation?  Perhaps more than the magnitude of the result.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are not very sure about the purpose of Simplify[]  function. Take it out of the expression and you will get the long full result.

```
    E^(-0.2` (1 - τ2)) (2^-(-21 + τ1)^2 Sin[
     1.256` + π (-21 + τ1)] + 
   2^-(-20 + τ1)^2 Sin[
     1.256` + π (-20 + τ1)]) (2^-(-21 + τ2)^2 Sin[
     1.256` + π (-21 + τ2)] + 
   2^-(-20 + τ2)^2 Sin[1.256` + π (-20 + τ2)]) Sin[
  0.9797958971132712` (1 - τ2)] (1/2 E^(-0.2` (1 - τ1)) Sin[
     0.9797958971132712` (1 - τ1)] + 
   E^(-0.2` (-τ1 + τ2)) Sin[
     0.9797958971132712` (-τ1 + τ2)])
```

Which results in a long expression that you may inspect. Also try substitute Simplify with N and also eliminate some precision from the code.